# Samsung Laptop cuts out at 37% battery life

Tags: windows-7, laptop, battery, low-power

I use a Samsung i5 (I think, I'm nowhere near the box to check specifics) laptop purchased summer of last year, running Windows 7 with a Quad core and AMD Radeon graphics. I'm pretty gentle with it, and leave it plugged in while using intensive programs, but within the last month my battery life has been strange. It would normally run down to 15%, give a warning, and shut off by 10 if I hadn't plugged in. Now I get about 37% and no warning- I've been exceedingly glad of Word's backup feature.

As a matter of course, it's always run a bit warm and I keep the vent clear, so I don't think it's overheating (I've been vigilant, having two pets). It's also set to Power Saver when unplugged with the lowest brightness settings, so I should have about 3 hours of battery life.

Any help much appreciated. I figured it'd be best to ask around before calling in my warranty.

Comment: Sounds like your charging habits are to blame for this behavior.  If you are not mobile, the battery should be removed ( you said it was a laptop not tablet ), to prolong the lifespan of the battery.  I would check the manual on how to update the battery status to reflect the new lifespan of the battery.

Comment: I've not heard of removing it before, but it's... not very practical when I come and go everyday, much as I'd like to adopt it. I'll check the manual when I get home later.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is , battery cells death of %37 . When you finish fully the battery several times , battery will recognize bad cells and drops max capacity lower. And it helps to use pc without any surprise shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

Try completely shutting it down, removing the battery, and putting it back in. The counter may be incorrect, and your batterys' health may be degrading. If that doesn't work, attempt to drain the battery fully then put it on charge until its full. If these don't work, you can download a utility to check your battery health (if your computer doesn't already have one), and you may want to consider replacing the battery.

Comment: I'll try when I get home later today. Do you know a reliable program to use for battery health? I don't seem to have one.

Comment: You could try CPUID's hwmonitor.